# Overpass-turbo: add city name to a specific node

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm requesting some drinking_water nodes by id:

```
node(id:1560728638,
1560728638,
1835271176,
1844271135
    ); out body;
```

I'd like to request the name of the city where the nodes are, for example:

| osm_id | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1560728638 | city A |
| 1560728638 | city A |
| 1835271176 | city B |
| 1844271135 | city C |

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the nodes already have a city tag: `"addr:city"`

You can ask and search question about overpass, OSM and various geographic queries on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com), it might be more focused that here.

Anyway, you can run the following query on overpass turbo:

```java
// output to .csv file, with columns
[out:csv(::type,::id,amenity, name, "addr:city")];
// list of nodes
node(id:1560728638,
1560728638,
1835271176,
1844271135
    );

//for each node:
// print the node,
// then get the surrounding (is_in),
// filter that for cities (admin_level 8),
// and return they city

 foreach->.d(
  .d out;   
  .d is_in;
  area._[admin_level~"[8]"];
 out;
   );
```

So you get a list of your original nodes (in a different order), and the city they're in.
They you can just extract the data from the file o put in in the format you want:

| @type | @id | amenity | name | addr:city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| node | 1835271176 | drinking_water |  | Privas |
| area | 3600087515 |  | Privas |  |
| node | 1560728638 | drinking_water |  | Privas |
| area | 3600087515 |  | Privas |  |
| node | 1844271135 | drinking_water |  | Saint-Etienne-de-Serre |
| area | 3602084772 |  | Saint-Étienne-de-Serre |  |